# Show that a line is parallel to trapezoid bases

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$$ABCD:AB||CD, AB \neq CD, AD = BC$$
$M$ is the midpoint of $AB$, $P = MD \cap AC$, $Q =MC \cap BD$; Show that $PQ||AB$ using symmetry. 
[image]
I've tried to show that $PP_1 = QQ_1$ ($PP_1\bot AB, P_1 \in AB; QQ_1 \bot AB, Q_1 \in AB$) but I think it isn't working. I've tried to use $MN$ where $N$ is the midpoint of $DC$ but I still can't figure it out. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Consider the side bisector $(s)$ of the side $A,B$, it passes through $M$ and is perpendicular on $AB$. Denote by $X'$ the image of a point $X$ w.r.t. reflection symmetry in $(s)$. What are the points $A'$, $B'$, $C'$, $D'$, $P'$, $Q'$? (Use incidence and the given symmetries.)

Comment: @dan_fulea, are you talking about $MN$?

Comment: If $N$ (undefined so far) is the middle of $CD$, then yes, $(s) = MN$. It is simple and important, please try to figure out the steps, and type the solution!

Comment: @dan_fulea, I defined it. See the explanation under the diagram.

Comment: @dan_fulea, so $\sigma_s: A \to B, B \to A, C \to D, D \to C$.

Comment: @dan_fulea, I am not sure how to show it but I think that $\sigma_s: P \to Q$.

Comment: Now $P$ is the intersection of the lines $AC$ and $MD$. Which are the images through $\sigma_s$ of these lines? Of their intersection?

Comment: Yes, so $PQ\to QP$, what does this mean? (Which lines are invariated by a reflection?) (I hope it is everything clear now! Type that solution! A longer discussion is rather less welcome here in the comments.)

Comment: @dan_fulea, oh $P \to Q$, thus $MN \bot PQ$. $MN \bot AB, MN \bot PQ$, thus $AB || PQ$?

Comment: Of course, correct! My version would have been $P\to Q$ and $Q\to P$, so $PQ\to QP=PQ$, so $PQ$ invariated, thus $\perp MN$, thus parallel to the bases.

Comment: @dan_fulea, can I ask how can I show that $MN \bot AB$?

Comment: The  the matical answer would be $A\to B$ and $B\to A$, exactly the same argument for $AB$ now as for $PQ$ above... (So also "by symmetry")

Comment: Thank you! Did you downvote my post? I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: Of course not my -1. Maybe people complain silently against the abrupt start without sentences, or $P_1$ was not defined for their taste, no idea. Your answer will be upvoted!